# UITableView cells with both UIActivityIndicator & UIProgressView

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview, reloaddata

I have a UITableView that contains several cells and some of them (the ones for files that are still uploading) have both an UIActivityIndicator and an UIProgressView. The ones for files that are finished use a different icon (instead of the activity indicator) and hide the progressview.

This table is using a NSFetchedResultsController as data source, so I get the updates on the data model and update the content.

Everything works just fine. The problem, however, is performance. Every time I call **reloadData** my UIActivityIndicators flicker, and it's not very smooth. Although I'm caching from the nib file, **reloadData** will have to calculate the new progress % for the ProgressView and I don't do anything with the ActivityIndicator other than hiding it if upload is complete.

Anybody ever tried something similar? Is there a workaround?

I was thinking about having an array of my progressview references and use that instead of calling reloadData.. not sure if this is the correct approach.

Thanks,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `reloadData` on the *UITableView*, all the cells of the table view are completely refreshed, re-assembled and redrawn. All the old ones are thrown away. This means that all the subviews of the *UITableViewCells* are removed and re-created too (including your *UIActivityIndicator* and *UIProgressView*). The refresh causes these views to flicker, or perhaps jump back to their start state. As there is no way of setting the frame of a *UIActivityIndicator*, your suggestion of restoring some progress value simply isn't possible.

Instead, perhaps you should try and engineer your "refresh" to not require a complete refresh of the table? For example, if you want to change the text of a *UITextField* within the view, you could simply access this text field and set the text property (no refresh is required). Or, if you want to hide your progress indicators, you could go into the appropriate object instances and set their property. You should design your app so that this is possible. Making changes this way avoids having to reload cells from scratch.

Besides the benefit of fixing your problem, using this method of updating, you should also see a large performance increase. `reloadData` is a very costly method to use and should be only used if it is absolutely necessary to really re-create the entire *UITableView* from scratch.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to work on a refresh method that will update an Array of references to my progressbars so I don't have to call reloadData. Will let you know how it goes, thanks again.